# Implementing Personality Equation to Multiple String

Tags: math, equation, differential-equations

I am trying to implement [Personality, Gender, and Age in the Language of Social Media](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3783449/#__abstractid1038491title) equation in an android Application on a List of String, By using Pattern and Matcher to find the matching words in the pattern.

I have 5 patterns and one list of 100 strings = 900 words. The result of find a Match in the 900 to the patterns were : 16 , 25, 5, 50, 10 words on each pattern respectively.

All that has been done, I am currently stuck in Implementing the equations mentioned in the Article to the data i got, So I can get values which can be converted to charts.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's rather unfortunate that you are stuck. Hope that you figure things out quickly.

Comment: (In other words, it's unclear what exactly you are asking. Can you clarify? Do you have code? If so, can you show it? What about the equations are you stuck on?)

Comment: @user3580294, I dont think any coded is needed here as its more Math solving.. Just explanation of the equation is what i need

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about solving a math problem.

Comment: Then you're probably better off on [Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) (if this is on-topic there, which it may not be). Generally Stack Overflow questions would involve code to some extent, such as if you tried to implement those questions, got wrong answers, tried *everything* you could -- debugging, rewriting, etc -- and still couldn't figure out what was going on. But if you just want an explanation of what those equations *mean*, then unfortunately this isn't the place to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for each phrase or word you have to calculate all the 3 formula.

The **first equation** gives you the pointwise mutual information of a phrase.

Lets say phrase = "best of luck"

So pmi = log(probability("best of luck")/(probability("best")x probability("of")x probability("luck")))

So **pmi is the log to the base 10 of the ratio of (probability of  phrase : multiplication of individual words probabilities)**

**Second equation** is the probability of phrase occurring in the subject and you can calculate it by division of (frequency of phrase used in the subject text) by (sum of the frequency of each phrase in the subject text)

For example, if the subject text is "Best of luck. You have long way to go.Best of luck."

Phrase = "Best of luck". The text has two phrases.

So pmi(phrase = "Best of luck") = frequency of "Best of luck"/(frequency("Best of luck")+(frequency of "You have long way to go"))

= 2/(2+1)

= 2/3

**Third equation** gives you the Anscombe transformed “relative frequencies” of words or phrases and you calculate it by the 2 multiplied by the square root of the (3/8 + output of 2nd equation)

= 2 x square root of (3/8 + 2/3)

= 2 x square root of 1.041

= 2 x 1.0202941

= 2.04